# How to clone/copy WeakHashMap? (Deep copy)

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy, weakhashmap

I had a HashMap and I used the clone function to make a deep copy. But I switched this to a WeakHashMap to try out some memory management.

I still want to do this clone function but it isn't part of the methods in WeakHashMap. How do I efficiently clone a WeakHashMap into another one? I suppose I could do a loop, adding keys and checking for existing keys etc, but I'm not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: The best way is the way you do in the next 5 minutes ... unless performance analysis shows it is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to copy all the elements contained in your map, a `for` loop is required in order to sequentially visit all key and value pairs.